# Unable to import views from an app in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, pycharm

I am trying to import views from my app "first_app", the command from first_app import views doesn't work in Pycharm. What am I doing wrong?
I also have tried: from first_project.first_app import views, but I get "ModuleNotFoundError" exception.

[image]

Comment: have you tried  from first_app.views import *

Comment: Yes, and that doesn't work too

Comment: Can't you do something like `path('route/',include('first_app.urls'))`? I know it is not importing it but it should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. When you're importing from your 'main' directory you just need to use the root indicator "."

```
from . import views
```

Comment: That also doesn't work too. I get "ImportError" exception.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you created a template and view yet? I noticed you're in Pycharm (which often displays false positive import errors with Django). If not, try creating those and import the views using 'from first_app import views as v'. the final url will be 'path("test/", v.test, name="test"),'. If that works then you should be able to just ignore the import error

Comment: I have views and templates, and everything looks correct. I found the solution, I simply marked the "first_app" directory as a source root and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution. If you have the same problem, you need to mark both of your directories as "source root". That did work for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).